# With the mini-profiler

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler

When using the mini profiler, does this mean production code will be 'littered' with using blocks?

```
using (profiler.Step("Set page title"))
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

I guess if it is 1-off testing I could remove it, but usually you want to keep these in the codebase for constant profiling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is actually a bad example - you wouldn't normally profile something trivial.

Ultimately, it is elective what you want to profile. There's a hook for things like ADO.NET, but if you want it to profile things *outside* of this, yes: you need to give it a hand.

Re "littered", well, that is subjective. And the best approach is usually to limit the instrumentation to **very high level** operations, and then only zoom in with more granular operations as you find you need to (due to an identified problem spot); for example, you might have:

```
...
using(profiler.Step("Refresh customer"))
{
    // ...
}
...
```

and then only when you find that taking 1800ms zoom in:

```
...
using(profiler.Step("Refresh customer"))
{
    using(profiler.Step("Query LDAP"))
    { ... }
    using(profiler.Step("Query primary customer DB"))
    { ... }
    using(profiler.Step("Query aux db"))
    { ... }
    using(profiler.Step("Print, scan, and OCR"))
    { ... }
}
...
```

There is also an `.Inline(...)` method for individual commands.

Whether or not you think this is "littering":

- it emphasises [performance is a feature](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html) (and indeed, often a requirement) - it is OK to have code to support your features! Indeed, it is a form of evidence that you have *considered* (and measured) performance of a new / altered piece of code
- it is entirely contextual how granular you make it
- it therefore provides a meaningful level of detail to the user - without insane amounts of trivia in the log, and without the performance-invasive nature of most logging

Comment: great thanks, btw, how did you make that dropdown on each page that outputs the results? did hook into the profiler somehow? i.e. save each log in request.items cache?

Comment: @codecompleting there is a pluggable API for providing both short-term and long-term storage. It uses an in-memory ASP.NET store by default, IIRC - but internally we use SQL-Server for long-term (it is easy to write a plugin for this). Was that the question?

Comment: I want to make something like: http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/2314/profiler.png  curious how you aggregate all the queries for a given request.  using request.items?